Differential equation involving square root
I am absolutely not familiar with differential equations. However, I am facing the following differential equation:
\begin{equation}
a(x)y^{\prime}(x)+b(x)y(x)=c(x)\sqrt{y^{2}(x)+d(x)}
\end{equation}
or written differently
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime}(x) = \tilde{p}(x)y(x)+ \tilde{q}(x)\sqrt{y^{2}(x)+ \tilde{r}(x)}
\end{equation}
If it helps, for simplification one can rewrite using some assumptions on $\tilde{p}(x)$ and $\tilde{q}(x)$
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{|h(x)|^{2}}\left(h(x)h^{\prime}(x)y(x)+q(x)\sqrt{y^{2}(x)+|h(x)|^{2}}\right)
\end{equation}
I checked Zwillinger's handbook on differential equations and Handbook of exact solutions for ordinary differential equations by Andrei Polyanin and Valentin Zaitsev in the hope to find differential equations having a similar form. However, I could not find anything similar.
I tried to solve this equation using MATLAB using the following code:
syms x p(x) q(x) r(x) y(x)
ySq = y(x)^2;
rSq = r(x)^2;
part1 = q(x)*sqrt(ySq + rSq);
part2 = p(x)*y(x);
ode = (diff(y,x) == part1 + part2)
ySol(x) = dsolve(ode)

however, this did not result in a solution. I do not know how to proceed. Can you help me making the next steps or pointing me even to the solution? Thank you very much.
EDIT:
Is it of any help if the differential equation is in one of the following forms?
\begin{align}
y^{\prime}(x) &= f(x)y(x)+g(x)\sqrt{y^{2}(x)+1}\\
y^{\prime}(x) &= g(x)\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}y(x)+\sqrt{y^{2}(x)+1}\right)
\end{align}

Is $h$  complex?

yes, it is complex, but if it helps for the solution, it is fine for now to assume that all functions are real-valued

If $h$ is real you arrive at Carlo Beenakker's solution under the transformation $y=h(x)u$, otherwise I cannot find a solution. Perhaps you can share the exact forms of $h$ and $q$?

thank you for clarification!

$$y^{\prime}(x) = f(x)y(x)+g(x)\sqrt{y^{2}(x)+1}.$$
for $f(x)\equiv 0$ the solution is
$$y(x)=\sinh\left(\int_c^x g(x')dx'\right),\;\;c\in\mathbb{R}.$$
I don't see a closed-form solution for nonzero $f$ (unless of course $g\equiv 0$).

Thanks for this comment. What I do not get is that if $\frac{d}{dx} sinh(f(x)) = cosh(f(x))\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ how can the following hold: $\frac{d}{dx},\sinh\left(\int_c^x g(x')dx'\right) = cosh\left(\int_c^x g(x')dx'\right)g(x) \overset{diffEq}{=} g(x)\sqrt{y^{2}(x)+1}$? Why is $cosh\left(\int_c^x g(x')dx'\right) = \sqrt{y^{2}(x)+1}$?

use $\cosh x=\sqrt{\sinh^2 x+1}$
